# Copying Variant Number of Rows to one matching row VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, match

[image]

[image]

Hi all,

On VBA, I am trying to match a variant number of row from one table into ONE row of another table (it's transposed) as long as the ID number matches. The code below only works for the first ID number (1A) but does not run for every other row I need in the results sheet. Any advice is greatly appreciated.
If it's any help, the "numbercount" is given for the variant columns (ex: ID 1A has 5 rows, so column D is the number 5)

```
          For i = 2 To finalrowi

           If wsExp.Cells(e, 1).Value = Workbooks(wr).Sheets(ws).Cells(p, 1).Value And 
           Workbooks(wr).Sheets(ws).Cells(p, 6).Value > 1 Then

          numbercount = Workbooks(wr).Sheets(ws).Cells(p, 6).Value 

          for p = 2 to (numbercount + 1)

          Workbooks(wr).Sheets(ws).Cells(p, 2).Copy 
                            
          wsExported.Cells(e, 2 + offset).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 
                    
          Workbooks(wr).Sheets(ws).Cells(p, 4).Copy
          
          wsExported.Cells(e, 3 + offset).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 
                    
          Workbooks(wr).Sheets(ws).Cells(p, 5).Copy

         wsExported.Cells(e, 4 + offset).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 
 
         offset = offset + 3
      
      Next p
end if

Next i
```

Comment: Sorry in the title I meant matching variant number of rows to one row

Comment: is it wsExp or wsExported, or are they different sheets?

Comment: Theyre the same sheet, just a typo

Comment: The cells being copied in your code are different from your screenshot - which is correct?

Comment: The code has correct cells. Screenshot is just a sample to explain what I want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (edited to account for empty cells)

```vb
Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, m As Variant, rngFill As Range
'...
'...

Set wsSrc = Workbooks(wr).Sheets(ws)

For i = 2 To wsSrc.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    If wsSrc.Cells(i, 6) > 0 Then
        'check for id match in ColA
        m = Application.Match(wsSrc.Cells(i, 1).Value, wsExported.Columns("A"), 0)
        If Not IsError(m) Then
            'got a match: get the first data block on matched row
            Set rngFill = wsExported.Cells(m, 2).Resize(1, 3)
            'check for existing data until have an empty 3-cell block
            Do While Application.CountA(rngFill) > 0
                Set rngFill = rngFill.Offset(0, 3) 'next block over
            Loop
            rngFill.Value = Array(wsSrc.Cells(i, 2), wsSrc.Cells(i, 4), wsSrc.Cells(i, 5))
        End If
    End If 'Col F > 0
Next i
```

Comment: `Dim m As Variant`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm getting a mismatch error on this line: m = Application.Match(wsSrc.Cells(i, 1).Value, wsExported.Columns("A"), 0)               Any idea as to why? Also the spreadsheet I want this to be displayed on has gaps in the columns on the result page that need to be filled in manually. Will this function still work?

Comment: and would the match function work if the 'data' page does not have a matching ID to the result page? Will it know to skip over that specific ID if not found?

Comment: The `IsError()` is used to check for a non-match.  Not sure what you mean by "gaps in the columns on the results page"  Do you mean (eg) B2:D2 could be empty but E2:G2 would have data, and you'd want B2:D2 filled first before filling H2:J2 ?

Comment: Sorry if this is not working out for you- I based my answer mostly on your screenshots: seems like they were not representative of what you actually want to do.